# WM_GETMINMAXINFO in AutoIt

Tags: windows, winapi, autoit

Is there a way to *send* the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message via AutoIt, in order to determine a window's maximum and minimum size? I can't find any examples of using PostMessage() to send a `struct`, although I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: You cannot use `PostMessage`, you must use `SendMessage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I think it should be. Based on a few tests it seems to work for some windows and not others? Not sure. But anyway, this creates the structure, and then uses `_SendMessage`.

```
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <SendMessage.au3>

Global Const $tagMINMAXINFO = "struct;long;long;endstruct;" & _
                            "struct;long MaxSizeX;long MaxSizeY;endstruct;" & _
                            "struct;long MaxPositionX;long MaxPositionY;endstruct;" & _
                            "struct;long MinTrackSizeX;long MinTrackSizeY;endstruct;" & _
                            "struct;long MaxTrackSizeX;long MaxTrackSizeY;endstruct;"

Local $tMMI = DllStructCreate($tagMINMAXINFO)
_SendMessage(WinGetHandle("Test"), $WM_GETMINMAXINFO, 0, $tMMI, 0, "wparam", "struct*")

ConsoleWrite(StringFormat("Max Size: %ix%i\n", DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MaxSizeX"), DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MaxSizeY")))
ConsoleWrite(StringFormat("Max Position: %ix%i\n", DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MaxPositionX"), DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MaxPositionY")))
ConsoleWrite(StringFormat("Min Track Size: %ix%i\n", DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MinTrackSizeX"), DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MinTrackSizeY")))
ConsoleWrite(StringFormat("Max Track Size: %ix%i\n", DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MaxTrackSizeX"), DllStructGetData($tMMI, "MaxTrackSizeY")))
```

Comment: Is there a difference between _SendMessage and just SendMessage?

Comment: @jasonhansel, `_SendMessage` is the AutoIt wrapper around `SendMessage`.